# Dense subset of $l^p$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let denote $A=\{e_n; n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where $e_i=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$ is the $i$-th unit vector.

Is $cl(span(A))=l^p$, ie. is $span(A)$ dense in $l^p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $a=(a^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in \ell^p$, let
$$a_k=(a_k^n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}:=\begin{cases}a^n & n\leq k \\ 
0 & n>k \end{cases} $$
be the sequence of sequences obtained by truncating $a$ at the $k$-th term.

Does then $a_k\to a$ in $\ell^p$?

Comment: I got it, thank you very much!